# Font weights seemingly not supported in Flutter web

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use Roboto's many supported weights in a Flutter web app. On iOS, all weights, from w100 to w900 are supported. On web, it seems there's only regular (w100 to w500) or bold (w600 to w900). What's going on? Are there any fonts that support many weights on web?

Comment: @pskink think they mean that using anything from 100-500 results in the same regular size, and anything from 600-900 results in the same bold size

Comment: @dantechguy silly me, too little coffee today ;-)

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

use this flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit for getting the exact result as on mobile